# fotorama plugin mouseout and mouseover

Tags: jquery, fotorama

If you choose `transition = crossfade` you will lose "mouseover and mouseout" (left arrow, right arrow) in/out animation.

You would see what I mean if you click this link http://fotorama.io/examples/transition.html and Select `Crossfade`.

Is there way to enable that even you choose Crossfade? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems fixed in the Fotorama 4.5.1.

Transitions are a little different from each other — arrows slide on slide transition, and fade on fade:

http://fotorama.io/examples/transition.html